# Configuring Sage by Roots.io - SASS issue

Tags: wordpress, sass, gulp

I am trying out Roots.io start-up theme Sage. I've just installed and configured everything locally and everything seemed to install correctly. However I am having issues with the SASS and JS files loading. I have followed the docs and installed everything correctly but the stylesheets and JS files aren't loading correctly. https://roots.io/sage/docs/.

If I check my source, I see the files are being compiled into one stylesheet and js file under:

```
/wp-content/themes/themename/dist/styles/main.css
/wp-content/themes/themename/dist/js/main.js
```

However, these files aren't being picked up when the pages are loaded. These links are leading to 404 pages.

Do I need to install anything else? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The files under the Assets folder are used instead, and dist folder is used to actually when releasing your product.